# remove a div in jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following code in which I want to delete a tag. But its not working.

**.CSHTML**

```
<div id="resultsection"> 
<span id="a83c970a-e899-4b0b-874f-a2a7d295a493" class="multiselectContainer"></span><br>
<span class="multiselectContainer">
 <span class="indivSelectedText">HIMANSHU_NOMATCH</span>
   <input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183386"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span>
<span class="multiselectContainer">
<span class="indivSelectedText">TEST_ASSOCIATION_BRANCH</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183301"><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose"></a><br></span></div>
```

**.js**

```
var prevElement= $(this).parents().find("#resultsection").find('.multiselectContainer');
```

Now, I have the following in the prevElement:

```
<span id="3906ab24-cfa3-46ac-9e65-15f6f98a582a" class="multiselectContainer">
<span class="indivSelectedText">MY BRANCH</span><input class="indivSelectedValue" type="hidden" value="183424"> <strong class="alert-warning"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-lg"></i><i class="fa fa-database">  </i> ,DATAHUB/ 8683403</strong><a class="fa fa-times-circle labelclose" href="#"></a></span>
```

But when I write **$(prevElement).remove()** or **prevElement.remove()** it is actually
not removing the div with class 'multiselectContainer'. How can I remove this element that I have in prevElement variable? .empty() works but it still have the "multiselectContainer" class?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Where is `this` coming from? Please share all your Javascript code. At least the function where `var prevElement= ...` is in.

Comment: Have you tried using `.closest()` function? e.g. `$(this).closest(".multiselectContainer")`

Comment: Are there several elements with id "resultsection" ? Why not `var prevElement= $("#resultsection .multiselectContainer');` ? You can only have one element with a given id.

Comment: @DenysSéguret: the "#resultsection" class have multiple ".multiselectContainer:" class and I want to delete one of it only

Comment: `find` doesn't return only one. It finds them all. You really should [build a code snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because your confused question is very unclear now.

Comment: @Yash you want all divs with class multiselectContainer to be deleted? or only one specific please be clear , you are confusing audience

Comment: @Yash which one you want to delete? from first or last?

Comment: if you have `#resultsection` which is supposed to be unique on the page you may just use `$('#resultsection').find('.multiselectContainer').remove();`

Comment: @markoffden - that would remove *all" `.multiSelectContainer`s

Comment: I have already mentioned in my code that the element that I have in variable prevValue, I want to delete that

Comment: @GeoffJames, nope. Only ones inside element with `resultsection` identifier, which as I said supposed to be a single instance element in the document.

Comment: @markoffden - If you look at the markup, there are 3 `.multiSelectContainer`s within the `#resultsection`

Comment: @GeoffJames, doesn't this mean the same `$(this).parents().find("#resultsection").find('.multiselectContainer');` ?

Comment: @Yash - just looking at your markup, your `<input>`s are invalid - they're not closed? Is this a typo or have you copy/pasted from code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve here, also I'm not sure what the `this` in your code is. But by looking at the code it should remove all divs with class `multiselectContainer`.

I tried to duplicate what I think you're doing in a jsfiddle really quick. I hope this helps you understanding your problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/kejgnpk8/1/

These are some basic examples of finding elements with jquery, but there is actually a lot more you can do to [select and find elements](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).